Torsion elements of finitely presented groups
Let $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_k ~|~ r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle$ be a finitely presented group with $n>1$ relators. What is known about the torsion elements of G and their relation to the relators $r_j$?
For one-relator groups ($n=1$), there is the theorem by Karrass, Magnus, and Solitar that says that $G$ has a non-trivial torsion element if $r_1=V^k$ with $k>1$ where $V$ is a non-empty word in $g_1,\ldots,g_k$, in which case every torsion element is conjugate to a power of $V$.  I'm basically wondering if a similar result exists for when $n>1$.
The closest result I found in the literature is the Theorem 4 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205157 for Coxeter groups. But based on the GAP docs for the LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup function, it seems a more general result is known to be true but I cannot find a reference for it.
Update: Based on Derek Holt comment, it seems unlikely that a straightforward generalization exists for $n>1$. One would still wonder if a similar result holds when one assumes further that all relators are a proper power, i.e. $r_i=V_i^{k_i}$ for some word $V_i$ (assumed not to be a true power) and number $k_i>1$. Is it true that any torsion element of $G$ is conjugate of a power of $V_j$ for some $j$?

I think it is very unlikely that you can say  much at all in general. There are non-obvious 2-generator 2-releator presentations of finite groups. For example $\langle x,y \mid x^2y^3, x^3y^2 \rangle$ is cyclic of order $5$, but neither relator is a proper power.

I see, thanks! What if all the relators are assumed to be a proper power of a word, i.e. $r_i=V_i^{k_i}$ (assuming $V_i$ is not a true power); is it true that any torsion element is conjugate of a power of $V_j$ for some $j$?

The answer is no, but it is best to avoid asking new questions in comments, so could you please edit your question and include this more precise question, and then I can answer it with a counterexample.

The result you are asking about holds for "combinatorially aspherical" group presentations.
One-relator presentations are combinatorially aspherical, as are for example small cancellation presentations.
A presentation is aspherical if its presentation complex is aspherical (this is the complex with a single vertex, loop edges correspond to generators, and relators are the gluing maps of $2$-cells). Combinatorial asphericity is a slight generalisation of this, which additionally allows for torsion.
As a concept in group theory, asphericity is about unique representations of identities $W=1$. If you are familiar with (van Kampen) diagrams, then if $W=1$ in the presentation $\langle X\mid R\rangle$, we may "tile" $W$ using the relators $R$ to obtain a diagram with boundary label $W$. If there is a second tiling of $W$ using $R$ which is suitably "different", then we may pin these two diagrams together across $W$ to obtain a spherical diagram. Being aspherical is about not having spherical diagrams like these.
There are a few inter-related definitions of "aspherical", which are explained in a paper of Chiswell, Collins and Huebschmann [1]. (Lyndon and Schupp's book has a flawed section on asphericity, and this paper is useful as it explains and then corrects the issues in this section.)
Huebschmann proved the relevant result, based on work of Serre [2, Theorem 3].
Theorem (Huebschmann , 1979).
Let $Q$ be a group with combinatorially aspherical presentation $\langle X\mid R\rangle$. If $x$ is an element (in $Q$) of order $1 <s <\infty$, there is a relator $r = z_r^{q_r}$ with root $z_r$, and an element $y\in Q$ such that $s|q_r$, and $x = yz^ty^{-1}$, $t = q_r/s$.
Moreover, if also $x = y'(z_{r'})^{t'}r’y’^{-1}$ with $z_{r'}$, the root of the relator $r'$ then $r = r'$, $t = t'$, and $y'\in yC_r$ where $C_r$ is the centraliser of $r$.
If you look at the theorem in Huebschmann's paper, there are two differences: he uses "aspherical" for "combinatorially aspherical", and he uses a tilde over letters, e.g. $\tilde{z}$, to denote the group representation of the letter.

[1] Chiswell, Ian M., Donald J. Collins, and Johannes Huebschmann. "Aspherical group presentations." Math. Z. 178 (1981): 1-36. EuMDL
[2] Huebschmann, Johannes. "Cohomology theory of aspherical groups and of small cancellation groups." J. Pure Appl. Algebra 14.2 (1979): 137-143. doi

A counterexample to the question at then of your post is $G = \langle x,y \mid x^3, y^3, (xy)^3, (xy^{-1})^3 \rangle$.
This is the nonabelian group of order $27$ and exponent $3$. I checked that with a computer calculation, but perhaps it could be done by hand?
The central element $[x,y]$ has order $3$ but is not a conjugate to a power of $x$, $y$, $xy$, or $xy^{-1}$, all of which are non-central.

Perhaps a simpler (silly) example is the finite Abelian group $\langle x,y,z\mid x^2,y^2,z^2,(xy)^2,(yz)^2\rangle$, where the element $xyz$ is a counterexample.

Thanks Derek and Steve, both these examples were very helpful!
